# Python writing on wrong row

Tags: python, web-scraping, google-sheets

I'm coding a **scraper** that send some client codes to a page, and If the code Is right It must write on the sheet some info of the page that will load. If the client code is wrong, then It must go to the next code on the sheet.

The same sheet send and receive the info. The client codes are on the first column and each one have It's own row to get the info.

The problem is that if the client code is wrong, the code is not ignoring that row when writing the info that get on the page previously. So in the end I get all the info written on sequenced rows (2, 3, 4, 5....) without skip none of them (witch should have be skipped if the client code does not returns any info).

k_bot.py

```
def search_cpfs(self):

    # SEARCH THROUGH THE LIST OF CLIENT CODES (1ST COLUMN OF THE SPREADSHEET), AND OBTAIN THESE INFO
    nomes = []
    idades = []
    beneficios = []
    concessoes = []
    salarios = []
    bancoss = []
    bancoscard = []
    consigs = []
    cards = []

    for cpf in self.cpfs:
        print(f"Procurando {cpf}.")
        self.driver.get(self.bot_url)

        #IF THE CLIENT CODE IS RIGHT
        try:
            cpf_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[1]/input')
            cpf_input.send_keys(cpf)

            cpfButton = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div/div[2]/button')
            cpfButton.click()

            time.sleep(2)

            self.delay = 2  # seconds

            nome = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/h2").text
            idade = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/ul/li[2]").text
            age = re.search(r'\((.*?)Anos', idade).group(1)
            beneficio = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/span/b").text
            concessao = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span").text
            salario = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/span").text
            bancos = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loans"]').text
            bancosw = re.findall(r'(?<=Banco )(\w+)', bancos)
            bankslist = ', '.join(bancosw)
            bancocard = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cards"]').text
            bcardw = re.findall(r'(?<=Banco )(\w+)', bancocard)
            bcardlist = ', '.join(bcardw)
            consig = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/span").text
            card = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                "/html/body/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/span").text

            print('CPF Valido')
            print(nome, age, beneficio, concessao, salario, bankslist, bcardlist, consig, card)

        # IF THE CLIENT CODE IS WRONG
        except (NoSuchElementException, UnexpectedAlertPresentException):
            print('CPF Invalido')
            continue

        nomes.append(nome)
        idades.append(age)
        beneficios.append(beneficio)
        concessoes.append(concessao)
        salarios.append(salario)
        bancoss.append(bankslist)
        bancoscard.append(bcardlist)
        consigs.append(consig)
        cards.append(card)

    return nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, bancoss, bancoscard, consigs, cards
```

cpf_updater.py

```
class CpfSearch(object):
    def __init__(self, spreadsheet_name):
        self.cpf_col = 1
        self.nome_col = 2
        self.age_col = 3
        self.beneficio_col = 4
        self.concessao_col = 5
        self.salario_col = 6
        self.bancos_col = 7
        self.bancocard_col = 8
        self.consig_col = 9
        self.card_col = 15

        scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
                 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']

        creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('CONSULTAS.json', scope)

        client = gspread.authorize(creds)

        self.sheet = client.open(spreadsheet_name).sheet1

    def process_cpf_list(self):

        # SKIP OVER COLUMN HEADING IN THE SPREADSHEET
        cpfs = self.sheet.col_values(self.cpf_col)[1:]

        bot_url = BOT(cpfs)
        nomes, idades, beneficios, concessoes, salarios, bancoss, bancoscard, consigs, cards = bot_url.search_cpfs()

        # UPDATE THE SHEET
        print("Atualizando...")

        for cpfs in range(len(nomes)):
            self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.nome_col, nomes[cpfs])
            self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.age_col, idades[cpfs])
            self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.beneficio_col, beneficios[cpfs])
            self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.concessao_col, concessoes[cpfs])
            self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.salario_col, salarios[cpfs])
            self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.bancos_col, bancoss[cpfs])
            self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.bancocard_col, bancoscard[cpfs])
            self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.consig_col, consigs[cpfs])
            self.sheet.update_cell(cpfs + 2, self.card_col, cards[cpfs])


cpf_updater = CpfSearch('TESTE')
cpf_updater.process_cpf_list()
```

Comment: What does it mean that the client code is right or wrong? What are you checking, and where are you checking it? It would be useful to add some comments in your code to make it easier to understand.

Comment: thanks man! I`v updated the code with comments, please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

You are using the lists `nomes`, `idades`, `beneficios`, etc. to store the data to write to your sheet. These lists are just a succession of values, and don't contain any information on which row is supposed to belong to each value. You are using the index of each element in the list to keep track of that (the first value in the `nomes` list should be written to the first row, and so on).

On the other side, you are appending values to `nomes`, `idades`, etc. only if the code is "right". If the code is "wrong", no value is appended to these lists because the keyword `continue` ends current iteration. This is a problem, because these lists should be keeping track of the rows in which the code is "wrong" (that is, where the cells should remain empty).

#### Solution:

You shouldn't just ignore the iterations in which the code is "wrong". Values should be appended to the corresponding lists disregarding whether the iteration's code is right or wrong. `nomes`, `idades` and so on should have empty elements in between non-empty ones to account for the rows in which the cells should remain empty.

An option in this case, if you want to keep blank cells for those rows, is to do the following in the `except` block: (1) assign `nome`, `idade`, and so on to empty strings, and (2) remove the `continue` keyword so that these empty strings get appended to the lists `nomes`, `idades`, etc.

#### Code sample:

```py
        # IF THE CLIENT CODE IS WRONG
        except (NoSuchElementException, UnexpectedAlertPresentException):
            print('CPF Invalido')
            nome = ""
            idade = ""
            beneficio = ""
            # Assign remaining variables to empty string...
```

Comment: Oh dude, thank you so mutch! It worked like a charm and will be very useful for me :) Sorry for my nooby question, It's my first time programming, trying to automate something for my worl. You helped me a lot, hugs from Brazil!

Comment: @MoisesFelipe you're welcome. I'm glad your issue could be solved.